# How to write a shell script that takes a name of a folder and deletes all subfolders?

Tags: command-substitution

I'm stuck with the script which I wrote on Bourne Shell.

Script:

```
echo "Who are you?"
read Individual
echo "Hello,$Individual"

echo "Where you want to go?"
read Path
grep -c "Path" file.txt
```

Comment: There does not seem to be any connection between the title of the question and the actual question.

Answer (score 1):

#### Sample data

```
$ mkdir -p dir{1..3}/dir{1..3}
$ tree dir*
dir1
├── dir1
├── dir2
└── dir3
dir2
├── dir1
├── dir2
└── dir3
dir3
├── dir1
├── dir2
└── dir3

9 directories, 0 files
```

#### The script

```
$ cat deletey.sh
#!/bin/bash

echo "Where you want to go?"
read Path
rm -fr $Path/*
```

#### Example run

```
$ ./deletey.sh
Where you want to go?
dir1
$
```

#### Result

```
$ tree dir*
dir1
dir2
├── dir1
├── dir2
└── dir3
dir3
├── dir1
├── dir2
└── dir3

6 directories, 0 files
```

#### Alternatives

Rather than use the `rm -fr $Path/*` you could opt to use a `find` instead:

*finds dirs in `$PATH` & deletes*

```
find $Path -mindepth 1 -type d -exec rm -fr '{}' +
```

*same as above, runs from inside `$PATH`*

```
find $Path -mindepth 1 -type d -execdir rm -fr '{}' +
```

Comment: @DanielDharmaraj - everyone has to start there, stick w/ it, it gets easier. Please mark this as accepted if you're all set.